# What is the language dependend country property on the current culture info object

Tags: c#, localization, globalization

I want to display a list of languages in a dropdown.

The user must see the countries in his own language.

As a german I want "**Deutschland**" for "de-DE" and "**Frankreich**" for "fr-FR"
As an english guy I want "**Germany**" for "de-DE" and "**French**" for "fr-FR"

I tried the .EnglishName, NativeName and DisplayName property on the culture info object, but thoese properties seem not correct.

Comment: Try `CultureInfo.DisplayName`

Comment: I think DisplayNames only contains the currently installed system language. There is no way to have all language names displayed in all possible translations, expect to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var item in from e in new string[] { "en-US", "en-GB", "de-DE", "ru-RU", "fr-FR" }
                     select CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(e))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1} (in current culture (russian): {2})", item.Name, item.NativeName, item.DisplayName);
}
```

Result:

```
en-US => English (United States) (in current culture (russian): Английский (США))
en-GB => English (United Kingdom) (in current culture (russian): Английский (Великобритания))
de-DE => Deutsch (Deutschland) (in current culture (russian): Немецкий (Германия))
ru-RU => русский (Россия) (in current culture (russian): Русский (Россия))
fr-FR => français (France) (in current culture (russian): Французский (Франция))
```

I think, `DisplayName` is depends on current UI culture, but `NativeName` is independent. For my culture (russian) all other cultures DisplayNames shown in russian, if I'll change current culture, `DisplayName` will change also. but I dont' know, how to get culture name `A` in culture `B` without change Windows settings.